# How to print to a HTML tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I have a Function in java script it should print to a tag in HTML page. My code is:

```
function print(i) {
    document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = line[i].toString();
};
```

The problem is my print() function is being called many times, so i am getting the output of the final value after the execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because each time, you are *resetting* the value of innerHTML. Changing `=` to `+=` will change it to what you want to achieve.